# Converter dicionarios de dicionarios em classe

Tags: python, classes

Possuo um dicionário que contém nome das atividades e algumas características dessa atividade.

Criei uma classe chamada processo e quero iterar no meu dicionário criando os processos.

```py
process_name = ['processo1', 'processo2', 'processo3']
process_data = {
    'processo1': {
        'prod': 1.2,
        'maquinario': 'maq1'
    },
    'processo2': {
        'prod': 0.7,
        'maquinario': 'maq2'
    },
    'processo3': {
        'prod': 0.9,
        'maquinario': 'maq3'
    }
}

# ______________________________

class Process(object):
    def __init__(self , dictionary):
        for key in dictionary:
            setattr(self, key, dictionary[key])
# ______________________________

for name in process_name:
    processo = Process(process_data[name])
    name = processo
```

Ele está criando o objeto com o nome `name` ou processo, e não com o nome do respectivo processo.

Como posso resolver isso? obrigado!

Comment: Cara, não entendi exatamente o que tu espera do código. Tu quer que ele salve também o nome do processo (que no caso seria `processo1, etc..`) ???

Comment: cara, quero que ele crie o objeto processo1,...

pra que eu possa ter o processo como uma classe, e poder acessar seus parametros, tipo: processo1.prod e etc

Comment: o que ele está me retornando é name.prod, ao invés do processo1.prod, por exemplo

Comment: Hmm.. Tu quer que o nome da variável seja o mesmo do processo. Não vejo a necessidade disso, mas se realmente precisa ter o mesmo nome porque não cria um dicionário e usa o nome como chave e o objeto como chave?

Comment: Não entendi.
1 - se eu nao colocar o nome da variável como nome do processo, como irei chamar a produtividade específica de um processo no código?

como está ali, ele está retornando o último elemento da lista, no caso o processo3 (nome.prod). Não consigo acessar o processo1.prod, por exemplo 

2 - não entendi a solução proposta

Comment: Na verdade o que propus é o que você já tentou fazer na linha com o código `name = processo`, porém isso não altera o dicionário original. Vou postar uma resposta com um exemplo e vê se resolve teu problema

Comment: blz!! obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está dentro do `for` na atribuição ao `nome`

```
for name in process_name:
    processo = Process(process_data[name])
    name = processo  # <------
```

A variável `name` é atribuída corretamente (apesar de não ter o efeito que você quer) mas é sobrescrita na próxima iteração do laço.

Para que você possa acessar os `Process` por nome basta substituir:

```
    name = processo
```

Por:

```
    process_data[name] = processo
```

Assim as alterações serão modificadas no dicionário original.

Abaixo um exemplo do seu código modificado:

```py
process_name = ['processo1', 'processo2', 'processo3']
process_data = {
    'processo1': {
        'prod': 1.2,
        'maquinario': 'maq1'
    },
    'processo2': {
        'prod': 0.7,
        'maquinario': 'maq2'
    },
    'processo3': {
        'prod': 0.9,
        'maquinario': 'maq3'
    }
}

# ______________________________
class Process(object):
    def __init__(self , dictionary):
        for key in dictionary:
            setattr(self, key, dictionary[key])

# ______________________________

for name in process_name:
    processo = Process(process_data[name])
    # única alteração no código
    process_data[name] = processo

# Dicionário atualizado com objetos do tipo Process
print(process_data)

# Acesso aos Process por nome
print(process_data['processo1'])
```

[Código funcionando](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/TatteredDishonestFilesize)

Comment: Agora sim entendi o que vc tentou falar antes ali. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Escrevi errado aquele comentário.. escrevi para colocar o nome com chave e o processo como **chave** era pra ser **valor**.  :)

Comment: Se a resposta do @fernandosavio resolveu seu problema e sanou suas dúvidas marque-a como correta para que a mesma possa no futuro ajudar outros que possuam a mesma dúvida.